# Python 3: dictionary doesnt contain all values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to save some values in a dictionary, but e.g if I give the input "Password1234!" and I print out the dictionary I get this:

```
{1: [5, -20], 7: [1.5, -10], 4: [2, -5]}
```

...where my "upper" value and elements are missing.
I´m sure I´m missing something very simple, but I dont get it, thx in advance.
This is my code:

```
password = input("password: ")
calculate(password)

def calculate(password):
    quantity = 0
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    digit = 0
    special = 0
    for i in password:
        quantity += 1
        if i.isupper():
            upper += 1
        elif i.islower():
            lower += 1
        elif i.isdigit():
            digit += 1
        else:
            special += 1
    
    types_list = {
        upper : [3, -10],
        lower : [1.5, -10],
        digit : [2, -5],
        special : [5, -20]
        }
    print(types_list)
```

output: {1: [5, -20], 7: [1.5, -10], 4: [2, -5]}

Comment: what is your code *supposed* to do? What's happening is that you are trying to map the same key to different values. Dictionary keys are unique, in your dict literal, the *last* key-value pair is kept.

Comment: You are overwriting the dictionary keys whenever the count for one of your digit types are identical. That is what happens here

Comment: bruh... thx guys :)

Answer (score 3):

> I´m sure I´m missing something very simple, but I dont get it,

Dictionary keys are unique. Since you have one `upper` letter and one `special` character, there are two keys `1`, so you create the dict:

```
{
    1 : [3, -10],
    lower : [1.5, -10],
    digit : [2, -5],
    1 : [5, -20]
}
```

and the second key `1` overwrites the first.

Your scheme really doesn't make much sense, why are you using counts as dict keys?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both variables `upper` and `special` correspond to the same key: `1`, and in a dictionary you can't have two identical keys, the second one will overwrite the first one. You should use a different approach, for example:

```
counts = {
  'upper': upper,
  'lower': lower,
  'digit': digit,
  'special': special,
}

types_list = {
  'upper': [3, -10],
  'lower': [1.5, -10],
  'digit': [2, -5],
  'special': [5, -20]
}
```

In this way you can know that, for example `'upper'` was typed `counts['upper'] == 1` time and has a value of `types_list['upper'] == [3, -10]`, for whatever that means.